# Laravel, only developing on remote server

Tags: laravel, frameworks, installation

Hello I have been wanting to get into working with a framework and Laravel seems like a decent one to try.

I have seen a lot of tutorials that tell you how to setup Laravel locally with Homestead or variants.

I am wanting to install and setup Laravel on my dedicated remote server with my hosting company. From there I want to be able to work with it on my local MacBook or MacPro.

I have not been able to find a good tutorial to make this happen in the fashion I want to do it.

I work with PHP and related daily but usually login to FTP and edit files with TextWrangler and save them and go about my day so my methods are dated and not efficient.

One side note is that I also have a Dell PowerEdge server running CentOS and VestaCP in my office as my development server so nothing is done locally per say (on my own computer) so the question and answer will apply to both my remote server and my remote but local development server.

Any suggestions are always welcome.

Best Regards,
Bradley

Comment: there is no difference at all, where you have problem? instead of editing the files locally you edit them with ftp, same same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have full root access to your remote servers, you should [install composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx) on them and [install Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation) in whichever way suits you. Then you can edit your project files just as if you were working on it locally.

Seriously though, the biggest thing you should add to your development arsenal (in case you haven't already) which will make your development process so much more resilient is **Git**.

Set up a [free Bitbucket account](https://bitbucket.org/account/signup/), get a [free Git client](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), and learn how commits, pushes, pulls, branches and deployments work. The easiest approach for deployment is to use a service such as [Envoyer](https://envoyer.io/).

That way you can develop and test locally (even if 'locally' is a remote machine) and not really have to worry about breaking your app by making a mistake in controller or something on the live server.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I got stalled when reading tutorials about install this and/or that to make it work and never seen anything for just remote functionality. Much appreciated! Happy Holidays

Comment: No problem. The Laravel docs should be your main source. Also check out [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) - a lot of free video tutorials there and Jeffrey is a very straightforward and clear teacher.